# Effect of factor vs vector object type when making a linear model

Tags: r, lm, anova, r-factor

What does explain the difference between the two `aov` below:

```
a = c(0.04875,0.13725,0.28350,0.50975,0.77425,0.94700,0.05325,0.14050,0.29725,0.51525,0.79000,0.95400,0.04625,0.15250,0.29000,0.53300,0.79825,0.95225,0.05025,0.14625,0.28800,0.52625,0.78200,0.95925,0.04700,0.14225,0.30325,0.53500,0.79325,0.95875,0.04775,0.13850,0.28675,0.54250,0.78300,0.95175,0.05150,0.12725,0.30175,0.54725,0.79475,0.96275,0.05375,0.14100,0.30050,0.53275,0.78100,0.96175,0.05450,0.15300,0.29650,0.52850,0.80100,0.95675,0.05425,0.13975,0.30875,0.56025,0.80575,0.96100,0.05100,0.15350,0.31175,0.53300,0.78900,0.96000,0.04650,0.13525,0.29600,0.53625,0.78475,0.96375,0.05375,0.13900,0.29600,0.53725,0.78700,0.95800,0.05075,0.14350,0.29225,0.54525,0.80275,0.95800,0.05050,0.13200,0.29850,0.52700,0.80525,0.96150,0.05150,0.14050,0.29450,0.54375,0.79450,0.96375,0.05375,0.13525,0.30475,0.55250,0.79425,0.96025,0.04950,0.14500,0.29425,0.52250,0.78475,0.95650,0.05225,0.14425,0.29225,0.53150,0.80425,0.95375)
b = c(4,4,4,4,4,4,6,6,6,6,6,6,8,8,8,8,8,8,10,10,10,10,10,10,12,12,12,12,12,12,14,14,14,14,14,14,16,16,16,16,16,16,18,18,18,18,18,18,20,20,20,20,20,20,22,22,22,22,22,22,24,24,24,24,24,24,26,26,26,26,26,26,28,28,28,28,28,28,30,30,30,30,30,30,32,32,32,32,32,32,34,34,34,34,34,34,36,36,36,36,36,36,38,38,38,38,38,38,40,40,40,40,40,40)
c = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6)


summary(lm(a~b*as.factor(c)))
summary(lm(a~b*c))
```

Does it mean that `c` is considered as non-ordinal when using as.factor?

Comment: Doing it as a factor treats it as a series of dummy variables, one for each level of `c`. Otherwise it's treated as a numeric/interval variable.

Comment: This isn't really about coding. If you have more statistics questions. [cross-validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) is probably a better place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases, you are exploring `a` as a function of `b` and `c` and their interactions.

When you coerce `c` to a factor, dummy variables are computed for each distinct value of `c` *(in reality each level of `c`, but in this case all levels are present, so these are the same)*.  So the interaction explored is between each value of `c` with `b`.

Otherwise, the interaction explored is that of a numeric variable.

The difference might be more clear if `c` were to have more drastic value differences, ie

```
c = c(1, 17, 2, 5, 131, 1, 4, 5, 2, 11, 17, 7, 1, 1, 17, .... etc)
```

---

Also, on a side note when learning `R`, avoid using `c` as a variable name. It is also the name of a heavily used function and it will quickly make code unreadable and lead to possible confusions

Answer (score 0):

You can examine the structure of the models created by looking at their model.matrix() results, since the `model.matrix` functions is what is used by the `lm` function to construct the data for analysis from the RHS of the formula:

```
> dim(model.matrix(~b*as.factor(c)))
[1] 114  12
> dim( model.matrix(~b*c))
[1] 114   4

> colnames(model.matrix(~b*as.factor(c)))
 [1] "(Intercept)"     "b"               "as.factor(c)2"   "as.factor(c)3"  
 [5] "as.factor(c)4"   "as.factor(c)5"   "as.factor(c)6"   "b:as.factor(c)2"
 [9] "b:as.factor(c)3" "b:as.factor(c)4" "b:as.factor(c)5" "b:as.factor(c)6"
> colnames( model.matrix(~b*c))
[1] "(Intercept)" "b"           "c"           "b:c"
```

The column names for the 'c'-variable in the second model are not separated into distinct levels as they were in the first model. The 'b:c'-column will be the product of 'b' and 'c':

```
> describe(b*c)
b * c 
      n missing  unique    Mean     .05     .10     .25     .50     .75     .90 
    114       0      67      77    12.0    16.6    30.5    62.0   111.5   160.0 
    .95 
  190.7 

lowest :   4   6   8  10  12, highest: 200 204 216 228 240 
> describe(model.matrix(~b*c)[, "b:c"])
model.matrix(~b * c)[, "b:c"] 
      n missing  unique    Mean     .05     .10     .25     .50     .75     .90 
    114       0      67      77    12.0    16.6    30.5    62.0   111.5   160.0 
    .95 
  190.7 

lowest :   4   6   8  10  12, highest: 200 204 216 228 240
```